# GStreamer 1.17 webrtcbin creates offer with "m=application 0"

Tags: gstreamer, sdp

This is not a problem for browsers, but for Kurento Media Server, which refuses to accept this. I think it is in accordance to the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3264

Is there any way to make it use another port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is to munge the SDP and change the port to something different